# Managing laptops and desktops in the organization and pushing windows updates to them

Tags: windows, windows-7, updates, inventory

Here are the couple of things we are trying to achieve

Our staff currently uses a bunch of desktops and laptops. Around 30-5o of the staff, most of them are laptops (mix of HP and Lenovo). Most using Win 7 professional , a minority using XP. What is the best way to

1. Manage pushing the windows updates to everyone's computer since not every one installs the updates by themselves.
2. Managing inventory through a software so that we know how many computers are there, who is using which one, which are currently being used and which ones are in repair.
3. Good to have feature would also be able to install software remotely and perfom maintenance remotely.

I am fine with a solution that may not solve all the above so would love to know which one can help with most of these issues.

Thank you.

Comment: It will be fine to have more than one software. We also use Google apps for internal conversation.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: You meant to ask this on http://serverfault.com — stick around and it should be migrated there

Comment: Sorry did not knew about Serverfault. Will post this issues there next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Software Management Solution, and Microsoft provides just such a server/client infrastructure.
http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/configurationmanager/en/us/sms.aspx

Google also launched an open source effort last year to reduce the cost of software licenses by allowing employees to visit the tool, and uninstall apps.  Not quite what your looking for, but you could likely extend their offering  to get some use.

http://code.google.com/p/appreduce/